# Mongoose : filter then update document if it exists , otherwise create it

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In the following method , i'm trying to search for a document using an email adress i provide. If the document exists i want to update the _id field, otherwise i create a totally new document .

```
function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    var newUser = new User();

    newUser.name = profile.displayName;
    newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value.toString();

    options = { upsert: true, new: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true };
    update = { '_id': newUser._id };

    User.findOneAndUpdate({ 'email': profile.emails[0].value.toString() }, update, options, function (err, user) {
        newUser.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            newUser.token = newUser.generateJwt();
        });
    });
    return done(null, newUser);
}
```

i get the following error in the console :

> events.js:183
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ BulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error index: databasename.users.$*id* dup key

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using `upsert : true`. This will create the document if not found

```
  User.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, function(error, result) {
   if (error) return;

    // do something with the document
  });
```

ps. You don't need to do `newUser.save(..)`. That'll do that for you if not found.
But I don't know why are you trying to update the `id` as this would cause fatal consequences